# Highmaps drillup: Error occurs when setting state in React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

The goal is to keep track of which region/area the user is currently in as they drill-down and drill-up on the map. I am accomplishing this with a state in my react component, however, I get a `TypeError: h.remove is not a function` error when I simply try to set the state within the drill-up event function.

[image: image of error]

I believe this is an **issue within the Highcharts library** and not my own code, but please let me know otherwise as well as if there are any workarounds for the issue.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-w6grg?file=/demo.jsx) is my sample code to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `drillupall` callback instead of `drillup`.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-xpk9o

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.drillupall